# Access MySQL Database Of A 'Per Project' Installation of Laravel Homestead

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, homestead, coda

I've installed Laravel Homestead on Vagrant via the 'per project' method outlined here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#per-project-installation

I can access the project database via ssh but want to be able to connect to it via my db editor (Coda).

My project root is `~/Code5`
and my `~/Code5/Homestead.yaml` file looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
version: "0.3.3"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: code5
name: code5
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Users/me/Code5"
      to: "/home/vagrant/code5"

sites:
    - map: super.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/code5/app/super/public"

databases:
    - super_db
```

Accessing `super_db` via ssh looks like this...

```
my-mac:~ me$ cd ~/Code5
my-mac:Code5 me$ vagrant ssh
vagrant@code5:~$ mysql --user=homestead --password=secret
mysql> use super_db;
mysql> show tables;
```

(tables listed successfully)

But If I try use this login config in Coda to access my database...

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 (port 33060)
User: homestead
Pass: secret
```

...I can't get it to connect.

(which is how I would connect on a global Homestead install, as opposed to a 'per project' method)

Also tried...

```
Server: code5 (port 33060)
User: homestead
Pass: secret
```

FYI: I needed to install Homestead via the 'per project' approach as I needed to run an older version of Homestead (that runs php5) without messing with my current global installation of homestead box (which runs php7). This way I can vagrant up either the php5 or php7 box and get developing.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, figured it out, used the IP from the Homestead.yaml file and changed the port back to the default (3306, not 33060) e.g.

```
Server: 192.168.10.10 (port 3306)
User: homestead
Pass: secret
```